# How to aggregate data from different sources in QGIS into one table

Tags: wfs, attribute-joins

This is a very basic beginner question and i need just a direction what keywords to look for.

I have GPS waypoint data from my GPS tracker. Just Long + Lat + Id.

And i have infos from a wfs server as another layer. This wfs layer provides polygons with different infos like "area number" or "responsible manager"

Every GPS point is located within of some of the polygon.

How do i join/connect this info with my GPS points, so that i have a (attribute) table which looks like

Long, Lat, Id, area number, responsible manager

---

xxxxx, yyyy, 1, 10, John Doe

...

Or is my way of thinking about processing data in QGIS wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Join attributes by location` does what you're looking for. Your GPS-data is the first layer you hand to the tool, the WFS service the second.

Comment: Yes this looks like what i am looking for. Let me try it first later before i mark as accepted :)

Comment: Is it the same like "spatial joins" ?

Comment: Yes, that is a term describing processes like these.